# RESTful JSON Parsing with angularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I 'am working in a restful web application that uses symfony2 as backend and angularjs in frontend,my problem is that I should receive json URLs with ajax,this is my code:

```
 <script>
function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http)
{
$http({method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost/onlinefacturation/web/app_dev.php/clientapi/clients.json'}).success(function(data)
{
$scope.posts = data; // response data 
});
}
</script>
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" >
<ul>
  <li>{{post.id}}</li>
  <li>{{post.nom}}</li>
  <li>{{post.prenom}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

this is the console error that I get,plus,I didn't get any data in the View:

```
 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
angular.js:11383 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PostsCtrlAjax' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=PostsCtrlAjax&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:80:12)
    at assertArg (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:1577:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:1587:3)
    at http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:8333:9
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:622:22
    at http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:7507:34
    at forEach (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:347:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:7494:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:6993:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:7632:24)
```

thanks for help

update:
this is the index.html:

```
html lang="en" data-ng-app="app" >
<head> ...... </head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div class="app" id="app" ng-class="{'app-header-fixed':app.settings.headerFixed, 'app-aside-fixed':app.settings.asideFixed, 'app-aside-folded':app.settings.asideFolded, 'app-aside-dock':app.settings.asideDock, 'container':app.settings.container}" ui-view></div>.........</body></html>
```

abd this is the file .html in which I want to get data from the json file URL:

```
<script>function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http)
{
$http({method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost/onlinefacturation/web/app_dev.php/clientapi/clients.json'}).success(function(data)
{
$scope.posts = data; // response data 
});
}
</script>
    <div class="hbox hbox-auto-xs hbox-auto-sm" ng-init="
        app.settings.asideFolded = false; 
        app.settings.asideDock = false;
      "  data-ng-app="app" ng-app>
    <div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts" >
        <ul>
          <li>{{post.id}}</li>
          <li>{{post.nom}}</li>
          <li>{{post.prenom}}</li>
        </ul>
        </div>  
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Did you defined your controller in html `ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax"`

Comment: @Hareesh I have fellowed this tutoriel and it's supposed to work very well :/ but I steel can't display data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try you controller like this

```
app.controller('PostsCtrlAjax', ['$scope', '$http' ,function($scope,$http) {
   $http({method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost/onlinefacturation/web/app_dev.php/clientapi/clients.json'})
   .success(function(data){
        $scope.posts = data; // response data 
   });
}]);
```

Comment: still the same problem,can't get data :(

Comment: Still showing `Argument 'PostsCtrlAjax' is not a function, got undefined` error?